# SQL Bigquery - Create a data set from 3 tables with master records and no duplicates with ARRAY_AGG(Struct)

Tags: sql, struct, google-bigquery, looker, array-agg

I am trying to query 3 tables to create one data set with master item data, transaction data and then serial numbers/locations.
My left table is a unique key for each item mentioned once, then the transaction data and serial data has the key repeating many times and I would like them to be a collection under the item for use in Looker Studio.

I have this working for Item to Transaction and Item to Serial but when I put all together I get loops and repeats of Data.

Here is an example of the tables
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBuHi.png)

Here is the desired output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLjVI.png)

```
ItemCode
Manufacturer
Model
Qty on Order
Transaction
    Date
    Qty
Location
    WH-Bin
    Serial
    Qty
```

Here is the code I have working to join two of the tables...

```
with nested as (

  SELECT
    i.ItemCode,i.Manuf,i.ItemName,i.QtyonOrder,i.AvgPrice,
    array_agg(struct (t.Date, t.Quanitty)) as Transactions, 

  FROM
    ItemMasterData i

  Left join
    Transactions t on i.ItemCode = t.ItemCode

  group by i.ItemCode,i.Manuf,i.ItemName,i.QtyonOrder,i.AvgPrice,
)

 
Select * from nested,
```

When I tied adding another

```
array_agg(struct (l.WHBin, l.Serial, l.Qty)) as Transactions,

Left Join Transactions l on i.ItemCode = l.ItemCode
```

I ended up having loops filling the blanks of inventory and transaction data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use the sub select to generate arrays inside a table.

```sql
With ItemMasterData as (Select *, rand()*1000 as info_fields  from unnest(["IT0001","IT0002"]) ItemCode ),
Transactions as (Select ItemCode, Date from ItemMasterData,unnest(generate_date_array("2022-01-01","2022-01-03")) as Date),
Location as (Select ItemCode, rand()*100 as loc from unnest(["IT0001","IT0002","IT---"]) ItemCode,unnest(generate_array(1,5)) as Date)

select ItemCode , info_fields,
((Select array_agg(struct(date,"..." as other_fields)) from Transactions t where i.ItemCode=t.ItemCode group by ItemCode )) as Transactions,
((Select array_agg(struct(loc,"---" as another_fields)) from Location L where i.ItemCode=L.ItemCode group by ItemCode )) as Locations,

from
 ItemMasterData i
```

Another way is to generate a row number and combine the tables by this as well.

```sql
With ItemMasterData as (Select *, rand()*1000 as info_fields  from unnest(["IT0001","IT0002"]) ItemCode ),
Transactions as (Select ItemCode, Date from ItemMasterData,unnest(generate_date_array("2022-01-01","2022-01-03")) as Date),
Location as (Select ItemCode, rand()*100 as loc from unnest(["IT0001","IT0002","IT---"]) ItemCode,unnest(generate_array(1,5)) as Date)

select * #except(dummy_row),
from
 ItemMasterData

Left join
  (Select *, row_number() over (partition by ItemCode) as dummy_row from Transactions)
  using(ItemCode) 
full join
  (Select *,row_number() over (partition by ItemCode) as dummy_row from Location)
  using(ItemCode,dummy_row)

group by 1
order by 1,2
```